# Expanding/Contracting Textarea on Typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to have a comment field that will grow to show all text when the user clicks on it and then shrink back down (hiding the unshowable text) when the user clicks out of the text area.  The user should be able to type in text and modify what they see.

I am assuming that textarea is the way to go since input doesn't have multi-line functionality.  However, I am a little stuck on how to implement this.  It seems everything out there just has the textarea resize to fit the text but not shrink back down after the user is done typing in it.

Could someone help me out/point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: does it have to be a `textarea`, or could it be a `div` with `contenteditable`?

Comment: A div with contenteditable could work.  However, I have created a server that stores/updates the textarea so I am not sure I gain anything by using the div.  I could be missing something though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `:focus` and `:active` states to change the textbox once the user clicks on it. Something like:

```
textarea{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 resize: none;
}

textarea:focus,
textarea:active{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Once the user clicks into the space, the text box will expand to the new dimensions. These work very similarly to `:hover`, if you're familiar with adding hover states.

Demo in a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/culil/1/

---

To add this stylings to you page you have two options.

1: You can include it as a css class in your site's stylesheet:

Css:

```
.parentcontainer > textarea:focus,
.parentcontainer > textarea:active {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

This is a best practice because it separates the concerns of styling ( which should be CSS ) and adding interactivity ( which should be JavaScript).

2: You can add the class before you append the element using javascript:

css:

```
.your-textarea-class:focus,
.your-textarea-class:active{
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
}
```

js:

```
$(function(){
  var textarea = $(".parentDiv").append("<textarea></textarea>");
  $("textarea").addClass("my-textarea-class"); 
});
```

http://jsbin.com/buhado/1/edit

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP intended. The OP specifically wanted *all* the text to display when the textarea is focused. We don't know how much text is in the textarea, so, therefore, we cannot use pixel heights/widths when focused.

Comment: @Jason setting width and height is only an example. The OP can use the  focus and active states to accomplish his goal with whatever properties he chooses to visually truncate the display of the text.

Comment: That example looks like it will work just fine for me.  The amount of expansion is probably left arbitrary and I think the size mentioned here suits my needs.  The textarea doesn't have to fit all text unless that's easy to implement via counting chars in the text area or something.  However, I am unfamiliar with :focus and :active.  How do I call them in javascript?  I am appending the textarea to elements via javascript.

Comment: Awesome thank you.  One last question: I have noticed that when I click on the textarea it expands as it should and then if I have manually adjust its size via the grab handle and then click out of the textarea it doesn't shrink as it should.  It seems to only shrink when I don't try to manually adjust its size.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @DarthHexamal you can just add `resize: none;` to the textarea to disable . That way you'll have the fine grained control over the look and feel of the textarea you're looking for.